# Sum of values from xml file using JSTL

Tags: xml, jstl

i'm using JSTL in a JSP page to read an xml file

everything works perfect and i'm able to loop through the file and read the values using this code

```
<x:forEach select="$resultatXML/users/user" var="user">
        <tr>
            <td><x:out select="$user/@num"></x:out></td>
            <td><x:out select="$user/name"></x:out></td>
            <td><x:out select="$user/credit"></x:out></td>
        </tr>   
    </x:forEach>
```

what i want now is the sum of all $user/credit of all rows, i couldn't do it because it gives me error when i try to set a variable with

```
<x:set var="credit" select="$user/credit" scope="page"/>
<c:out value="${pageScope.credit }"/>
```

it gives me

```
[[credit: null]]
```

all i want now us the sum of all credits

Comment: at the risk of being considered trolling, I have to make the observation that what you're doing (xml parsing) is 'business logic', not simple data display, and so should be done in appropriate back-end  business-logic code, not in a 'view' technology like JSP/JSTL. The reason that you're finding it difficult to do there is because you're using the wrong tool. Hit the nail with a hammer instead of a screwdriver, and things will go much easier.

Comment: i fully understand you, thank you so much for the observation, unfortunately, this is a school project in which it is mentioned we should do this only with jsp/jstl... thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this simply by doing the addition part with jstl core.

Before you iterate create a sum variable.

```
<c:set var="sum" value="0"/>

<x:forEach select="$resultatXML/users/user" var="user">
    <tr>
        ...
        ...
        ...
```

Extract user credit in a jstl xml variable

```
        <x:set var="userCredit" select="$user/credit"/>
        <td><x:out select="$userCredit"></x:out></td>
    </tr>
```

Add to the sum before loop ends. jstl will perform appropriate coercion to the value.

```
    <c:set var="sum" value="${sum + userCredit}"/>
</x:forEach>
```

Finally you can just print the sum.

```
<c:out value="${sum}"/>
```